# Parsing input into emoji with Twemoji

Tags: javascript

So I have setup a codepen here to demonstrate my issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNYzXx

```
var emojiString = "I \u2764\uFE0F emoji!";        

var parsedString = twemoji.parse(emojiString);
$('#string-result').html(parsedString);

var parsedInput = twemoji.parse($('#emoji-input').val());
$('#input-result').html(parsedInput);
```

If I type the text "I \u2764\uFE0F emoji!" into the input box and click go I expect the same result on both lines instead the input text isn't parsed but the variable is.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This is the same problem I am having. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably typed `I \u2764\uFE0F emoji!` in the input field. When you type that in the input field, you actually get the string `"I \\u2764\\uFE0F emoji!"` instead of the string `"I \u2764\uFE0F emoji!"`, notice the extra `\`.

In your variable, in the string literal `"I \u2764\uFE0F emoji!"`, that `\` in `\u2764` has a special meaning, it is a scape character. Instead of representing the character `\` it actually indicates that `\u2764` represents an Unicode code point. The code points `\u2764` and `\uFE0F` together form the heart character. In other words `"\u2764\uFE0F"` is a code that represents just one character.

When you type `I \u2764\uFE0F emoji!` in the input field, you didn't type the heart character, you actually passed the regular `\` character. Since the `\` have a special meaning, we represent it in a string like this`\\`, so that is why the string from the input field looks different.

So basically you typed JavaScript code that represents the character that you wanted to type, instead of the character itself. We can fix this by evaluating what you typed like it was JavaScript code. If you replace `var parsedInput = twemoji.parse($('#emoji-input').val());` by `var parsedInput = twemoji.parse(eval("'" + $('#emoji-input').val() + "'"));` the code will work as expected. Also, avoid using eval, because it will run anything passed to it.